# 19 orders either "Cancelled" or "Payment declined" is this a coincidence or can a faulty implementation of billing library on my side cause this

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, google-play-console, android-billing

On one of my new apps I received 19 individual orders yesterday, but not a single one of them went through, could I have improperly implemented the billing library, can a developer side issue cause this.

Answer (score 0):

If the cancellations are apparently from the same user, all from the same country, then probably that person have a problem with their payment method.

If the cancellations are of various origins then probably you have a problem in your code, maybe you are not calling `billingClient.acknowledgePurchase()` ?

Comment: Thanks Lluis Felisart, I am acknowledging purchase, I have received one payment on 21st may, but every single order since then has been cancelled or declined.I  have since received 5 more orders that are either cancelled or declined,

Comment: @LangOne have you got any solution to this? I am getting the customer payment declined for many of my customers